# Unable to re register custom NodeTypes if it has any mandatory nodetype property update(removal) in apache Jackrabbit 2.17.5

Tags: java, apache, jcr, jackrabbit

Start: lets say I have some custom node types as below.

```
    <test = 'http://abcd.com/test'>
    <nt='http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0'>
    <mix='http://www.jcp.org/jcr/mix/1.0'>

    [test:base] > nt:base
    - name (string) mandatory version
    - data (long) mandatory version
    - category (string) version multiple
    - version (string) version

    [test:file] > nt:file
    - filename (string) mandatory

    [test:template] > test:base
    + * (test:file) version

After that I changed the above custom properties as :

    <test = 'http://abcd.com/test'>
    <nt='http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0'>
    <mix='http://www.jcp.org/jcr/mix/1.0'>

    [test:base] > nt:base
    - name (string) mandatory version
    - category (string) version multiple
    - version (string) version

    [test:file] > nt:file
    - filename (string) mandatory

    [test:template] > test:base
    + * (test:file) version
```

Here i removed the property "data" and trying to re register using
       CndImporter.registerNodeTypes(...);

Now when i'm trying to register nodetypes again i'm getting the error as fallows:

```
Caused by: javax.jcr.RepositoryException: The following node type change contains non-trivial changes.Up until now only trivial changes are supported. (see javadoc for org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.nodetype.NodeTypeDefDiff):
org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.nodetype.NodeTypeDefDiff[
    nodeTypeName={http://abcd.com/test}base,
    mixinFlagDiff=NONE,
    supertypesDiff=NONE,
    propertyDifferences=[
        org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.nodetype.NodeTypeDefDiff$PropDefDiff[itemName={}version, type=TRIVIAL, operation=MODIFIED],
        org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.nodetype.NodeTypeDefDiff$PropDefDiff[itemName={}data, type=MAJOR, operation=REMOVED],
        org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.nodetype.NodeTypeDefDiff$PropDefDiff[itemName={}name, type=TRIVIAL, operation=MODIFIED],
        org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.nodetype.NodeTypeDefDiff$PropDefDiff[itemName={}category, type=TRIVIAL, operation=MODIFIED]
    ],
    childNodeDifferences=[
    ]
]

    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.nodetype.NodeTypeRegistry.checkForConflictingContent(NodeTypeRegistry.java:947)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.nodetype.NodeTypeRegistry.reregisterNodeType(NodeTypeRegistry.java:435)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.nodetype.NodeTypeRegistry.reregisterNodeType(NodeTypeRegistry.java:384)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.nodetype.NodeTypeManagerImpl.registerNodeTypes(NodeTypeManagerImpl.java:596)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.cnd.CndImporter.registerNodeTypes(CndImporter.java:162)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.cnd.CndImporter.registerNodeTypes(CndImporter.java:110)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's by design. Removing the property definition might cause your repo content to become invalid.

What might work is changing the property definition to be optional.

Comment: You mean changing the mandatory "data" field to optional.

And also my use case is i don't want that property to my node-type.